# Do I need a DNS zone in Azure?

Tags: azure, dns-zone

I'm fairly new to the DNS concept and I'm trying to host my website on Azure cloud service.

I purchased a Domaine App Service in Azure this ensuring that I can redirect my web application to my own custom doamin name.

However, I don't really understood the concept of Zone DNS, and I'm wondering if I need one at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a custom domain name you've purchased from a domain provider you don't need to do anything with Azure DNS follow the instructions here to map the DNS name to the app service

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#cname

You can optionally use Azure DNS to host your DNS domain and manage your DNS records. By doing so you can manage your DNS records by using the same credentials and common interface.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a matter of fact, I purchased a domain name from Azure's portail, and it's already mapped to my web app. My only concern is that prior to doing this, I created " DNS zone" without knowing what it really was because I initially thought it was the way to buy my domain name. Now, I have both: domain name and DNS zone in my azure portail, and I'm wondering if I should delete the dns zone.

Comment: My understanding is that when you buy an App Service Domain a DNS Zone is created as well. So if you bought the domain contoso.com there would be a contoso.com DNS Zone resource created. This will hold the record sets for the domain you created and you shouldn't delete that. If you have created an entirely separate Zone then assuming there are no records in there, it could potentially be deleted. Exercise caution here, once you delete a zone it can't be undone, any services depending on it will fail when it is deleted.

Comment: this makes perfectly sense, I can see that in the "locks" section of my DNS Zone my domain name appears. Meaning that they intricately linked. I will stick with the zone. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.